# A String from hashing is no longer the same after output to a file and then input

Tags: java

Here is the weird thing which has already taken me a whole day:

If a write a simple String like "1" to a file and read it immediately, the string fetched `equals` the original String.

But if the String is generated by some hash function, the String fetched is **no longer the same**.

The follow code prints `true false`, and I want to know the trick behind the scene.

Thank you very much.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String s1 = "1";
        File f1 = new File("f1");
        write (s1, f1);
        System.out.println(read(f1).equals(s1));

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        String s2 = foo(new File("1.jpg"), md);
        File f2 = new File("f2");
        write (s2, f2);
        System.out.println(read(f2).equals(s2));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

// Hash <i>f</i> by <i>md</i>
static String foo (File f, MessageDigest md) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(fis, md);
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    while (dis.read(b, 0, 1024) != -1) {
    }
    md = dis.getMessageDigest();
    String s = new String(md.digest());
    dis.close();
    fis.close();
    return s;
}

static void write (String s, File f) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(s);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.close();
    fw.close();
}

static String read (File f) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String s;
    s = bf.readLine();
    bf.close();
    fr.close();
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your first problem:

```
String s = new String(md.digest());
```

You're creating a string with arbitrary binary data in the platform default encoding. It may well not *be* valid text data in the platform default encoding. In other words, you're losing data. Encode it with base-64 instead - that way you'll always have a string with ASCII characters, and can get back to the original binary data reliably.

Your second general problem is using `FileReader` and `FileWriter`. These *always* use the default platform encoding, which is a *terrible* API decision as it makes them almost useless in my view. You should almost always be specifying an encoding - I tend to use UTF-8. Use `FileInputStream`/`FileOutputStream` and `InputStreamReader`/`InputStreamWriter` to read/write text with files. (Or use the Guava helper routines.)

Comment: I would like to try this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The digest value of the hashed file most likely contains a newline or line feed character (0x10 or 0x13) which breaks the way you read the string using `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Comment: I do not think it is the problem. In the debugging mode, the 2 Strings look the same, at least in the specific case of mine. Thank you.